# How to validate number format TextField in wicket?

Tags: java, validation, numbers, wicket-6

In my maven-wicket (6.10) application I have a TextField, which has an Integer type property model. I want to set a maximum length for numberts to type into this TextField. (for example the user should write maximum 2 characters to the "age" text field)

I have tried this code:

```
add(new TextField<>("age",new PropertyModel<(personModel,"age"))
    .add(StringValidator.maximumLength(2)));
//age is an Integer value from a Person class, personModel is "IModel<Person>" type
```

but I got this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.apache.wicket.validation.validator.StringValidator.getValue(StringValidator.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.validation.validator.StringValidator.getValue(StringValidator.java:59)
    at org.apache.wicket.validation.validator.AbstractRangeValidator.validate(AbstractRangeValidator.java:107)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.validateValidators(FormComponent.java:1523)
```

So if the property model is not string type, I cannot use StringValidator. I have found examples, which use NumberValidator ([validators](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/validation/validator/package-summary.html)), but I cannot resolve NumberValidator. I have only these validators in the source:
[image: validation source]
How could I use number validator? Or am I missing something, maybe form the pom.xml's dependencies for wicket?

Comment: NumberTextField is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is related to the way Wicket works. First it converts input text into a model object and then it performs validation.

Thus, you have to use [RangeValidator](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/validation/validator/RangeValidator.html) instead of `StringValidator`

```
IModel<Integer> model =
    new PropertyModel<Integer>(personModel, "age");
Component ageField = new TextField<Integer>("age", model);
add(ageField).add(RangeValidator.<Integer>range(0, 99));
```

Note I've changes `Long` to `Integer` as I believe saving age as `Long` is not practical.

Also note that link to NumberValidator is for Wicket 1.4, while you are using Wicket 6. Wicket 6 is a large API change comparing to previous versions.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like good! But I made my own NumberFormatValidator, but your answer is good! :-)

Comment: Sure, defining your own validator is another way of doing it. This is the only solution, for example, if validated value must be in one of two ranges or odd.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference please have a look at [NumberTextField<N>](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/NumberTextField.html) 
In Op's case, you could do more easily like:

```
IModel<Integer> model = new PropertyModel<Integer>(personModel, "age");
add(new NumberTextField<Integer>("age", model).setMinimum(0).setMaximum(99));
```